# Projection of a Tastypie REST API into python objects

Tags: python, mysql, django, rest, sqlalchemy

I want to test web applications that were developed using Django framework and Tastypie.

My plan was to test the REST API calls of the web apps against the queries they perform on the MySql DB. In order to do so I've investigated a little bit about DB access framework, and have encountered SQLalchemy framework, and the reflection attitude.

My thought were to try and access the Web Apps REST API in the same attitude and test the results from both sources.

Can you please suggest a different approach for examining this problem? Is there framework that will help for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Testing with Tastypie is easy as they provide a special TestApiClient and ResourceTestCase which build on Django's testing api and tools and also provide a lot of helpful assertion methods.

The documentation is useful and has lots of examples:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to see what queries are generated by django ORM or tastepy?

I think one easy way is to do a wrappper arround the DB class, where you run the DB class method,  analise the results and print our save them to a file.

Another way to do this, is to use mysql slow_query_log with 0 seconds to log all the queries that are being made to MYSQL.
You can use a diferent user our schema to parse the results more easy.
Not good to test in production services :)